# Get Session ID for a Selenium RemoteWebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I'm trying to get a session id for a test being run on the SauceLabs cloud, but I can't seem to access it.

I've tried the following approaches:

```
//Returns null
var sessionId = (string)((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities.GetCapability("webdriver.remote.sessionid");

//Will not compile
sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).SessionId; //This is protected.
```

The second approach is particularly confusing. It's a protected property, but if I can only access this from a derived class, then it's essentially useless for what I need.

[image: Session ID]

Any help is appreciated.

In order for this to work, I had to create a class derived from `RemoteWebDriver` and then define a getter method. For example:

```
class  CustomeRemoteDriver : RemoteWebDriver
{

    public CustomeRemoteDriver(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities):base(desiredCapabilities)
    {
    }

    public CustomeRemoteDriver(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities):base(commandExecutor, desiredCapabilities)
    {
    }

    public CustomeRemoteDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities):base(remoteAddress, desiredCapabilities)
    {
    }

    public CustomeRemoteDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout):base(remoteAddress, desiredCapabilities, commandTimeout)
    {
    }

    public string GetSessionId()
    {
        return base.SessionId.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks almost like a `Casting` issue can you post what the actual error is it's hard to see the little image you  have posted

Comment: here is a guide that is online that may help you out .. also can you show how this Class is defined I may be able to provide you with an Idea but need to see the Class and how it's defined for your RemoteWebDriver..how are you inheriting this http://testingbot.com/support/getting-started/csharp.html

Comment: So, should I just create a derived class to cast my RemoteWebDriver to and then access the session id with a getter method?

Comment: Something like this `public CustomRemoteDriver(Uri uri, DesiredCapabilities capabilities)
            : base(uri, capabilities)
        {
        }
        public SessionId getExecutionID()
        {
            return ((CustomRemoteDriver)Driver.Browser.driver).SessionId;
}
}`

Comment: Yeah, I just did that. It works, but it's needlessly circuitous. Go ahead and add an answer and I'll give you the upvote.

Comment: Whilst I am glad you got your answer, why do you need access to the session ID?

Comment: Cool I will add the example

Comment: Arran, I'm using SauceLabs and in order to make pass/fail assertions I need to get the session/job id to build requests to submit to their REST API. There are other flags that can only be set using this method as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Example of what you could do

```
class  CustomeRemoteDriver : RemoteWebDriver
{    
    public CustomRemoteDriver(Uri uri, DesiredCapabilities capabilities) 
    : base(uri, capabilities)
    { 
    } 

    public SessionId getExecutionID() 
   { 
      return ((CustomRemoteDriver)Driver.Browser.driver).SessionId; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Could also reach in using reflection.

```
            var sessionIdProperty = typeof(RemoteWebDriver).GetProperty("SessionId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (sessionIdProperty != null)
            {
                SessionId sessionId = sessionIdProperty.GetValue(driver, null) as SessionId;
                if (sessionId == null)
                {
                    Trace.TraceWarning("Could not obtain SessionId.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("SessionId is " + sessionId.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply get sessionId:
by this

```
String sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver)webDriver).getSessionId().toString();
```

here

```
WebDriver webDriver = null;
```

already declared.

Comment: This doesn't work, as the RemoteWebDriver doesn't expose this method

Answer (score 1):

I am using `selenium-dotnet-2.48.0` and this is working just fine:

```
string sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities.GetCapability("webdriver.remote.sessionid").ToString();
```

Make sure you set video to True:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
...
capability.SetCapability("video", "True");
```

Answer (score 0):

using Selenium.WebDriver  Version="3.141.0", this is working:

```cs
string sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver)Driver).SessionId.ToString();
```