# how can I use selenium with my normal browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

Is it possible to connect selenium to the browser I use normally instead a driver?  For normal browsing I am using chrome with several plugins - add block plus, flashblock and several more. I want to try to load a site using this specific configuration. How can I do that?

p.s - I dont want to connect only to an open browser like in this question :

[How to connect to an already open browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766131/how-to-connect-to-an-already-open-browser)

I dont care if I spawn the process using a driver. I just want the full browser configuration - cookies,plugins,fonts etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to download the [`ChromeDriver`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver), then either put the path to the executeable to the `PATH` environment variable, or pass the path in the `executable_path` argument:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/executeable/chrome/driver')
```

In order to load extensions, you would need to set `ChromeOptions`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('Adblock-Plus_v1.4.1.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

You can also save the chrome user profile you have and load it to the `ChromeDriver`:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/path/to/my/profile')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

See also:

- [Running Selenium WebDriver using Python with extensions (.crx files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800689/running-webdriver-with-extensions-crx-files)
- [ChromeDriver capabilities/options](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about fonts? I would like to use the same fonts installed on my chrome for browsing in my webdriver. Can that be done?

Comment: @WeaselFox I'd try to save/load the user profile. I've updated the answer, hope it helps.