# Having issues getting selenium to navigate to a page being hosted by flask

Tags: python, windows, selenium, flask

I'm working on a social media branding tool using flask+selenium with python. It takes a few user inputs (e.g. title, subtitle etc) and then uses those input and selenium to navigate to another page, use the text to draw a title and then screenshot that page.

At the moment, this works on a mac, but trying to get it work on company owned Windows computer (which is slightly more locked down). The flask app runs but issues happen when it tries to use selenium. Have narrowed down the issue to where selenium is trying to navigate to the page served by flask

`driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/branding')`

The logs indicate a 500 error. The page is navigatable but just not from selenium. Any ideas about what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I use selenium to navigate to locally hosted web pages almost all of the time, one thing to note however is when you use chrome/firefox for automation it opens an 'automation' version of the browser, it doesn't save cookies, has no ability for extensions or addons and i guess when using an app this could make the page un-loadable.

So i think you need to follow this guide and use a fully-powered browser to cope with whatever your application is doing.

[>>> Tutorial Here <<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018286/how-can-i-use-selenium-with-my-normal-browser)